# $x_n=\sqrt{x_{n-1}\cdot x_{n+1}};n\geq 1$ the limit of $x_1+x_2+...+x_n=?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

So I have $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}};x_0=4;x_2=1$ and $x_n=\sqrt{x_{n-1}\cdot x_{n+1}};n\geq 1$ I need to find the limit of $x_1+x_2+...+x_n$

My try: I found the terms $x_1,x_2,x_3....=2,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}...$ so I have a sum of a geometric progression with ratio $1/2$ so I used to formula to find the sum then when I calculated the limit I got $4$ but in the book they say the limit is $8$.

Where's my mistake?

Comment: It sounds like they simply meant to ask for the limit of $x_0+x_1+\cdots+x_n$, and your work is correct.

Comment: $\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}=\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty x_n=2
$$

In fact: $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-2}}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=2.$$

Now it remains to sum $x_0$ and $x_1$ to the first sum. Hence:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=x_1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty x_n=2+2=4$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n=x_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=4+4=8$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I still don't understand.They ask me for limit from $x_1,x_2..$.Why do I need to count $x_0$ too ?

Comment: I think there is a typo somewhere. Maybe the author meant $x_0+\cdots+ x_n+\cdots$; in such a case the answer is $8$. Otherwise, if the author meant $x_1+\cdots +x_n+\cdots$ the answer would be $4$.

Comment: I got it.So my pproach is correct.Thanks!

Comment: Yes, nothing to say about your approach :)

Answer (score 4):

$x_n=\sqrt{x_{n-1}\cdot x_{n+1}}$, gives: $$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}=\dots=\frac{x_1}{x_0}=r$$

Let us call this ratio $r$, then $$x_1=rx_0\\x_2=rx_1=r^2x_0\\\vdots\\x_n=r^nx_0$$

Using that $x_2=1$ and $x_0=4$ we get $1=4r^2\Rightarrow r=1/2$. This yields:

$$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=x_0r+x_0r^2+\ldots+x_0r^n\\=4\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$$

This is a geometric series, which is equal to $$2\left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^n}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}\right)=4\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$$

Thus $$\boxed{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}4\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)=4}$$ ($8$, if the sum is $x_0+x_1+\ldots$)